# What do the following methods of writing intergrals and differentials mean.

Tags: calculus

I have seen the following occur many times in calculus and have solved a couple of questions too of the type:

$$
\frac{d(f(x))}{d(g(x))}
$$

i.e. differentiating one function wrt to another function.

And :

$$
\int_{a}^{b}f(x) d(g(x))
$$

what do both these mean, my questions in a line is what do these two mathematical statements mean, what are we doing when we are evaluating the above.

Comment: The first term only makes sense when $f$ is a function of $g$. That notation I have never seen. The second could be a Riemann-Stieltjes integral. Who knows ? One needs *context* and not just a formula.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the meaning of a differential (as opposed to a derivative)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159479/whats-the-meaning-of-a-differential-as-opposed-to-a-derivative)